# Meteor : Unexpected token var

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm getting this error on my meteor app and I can't seem identify what's the error.

```
server/twitter.js:13:7: Unexpected token var
```

This is the code :

```
var Twit = Meteor.npmRequire('twit');
var conf = JSON.parse(Assets.getText('twitter.json')); 

var T = new Twit
({
  consumer_key: conf.consumer.key, 
  consumer_secret: conf.consumer.secret,
  access_token: conf.access_token.key, 
  access_token_secret: conf.access_token.secret


  var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: conf.keyword })

  stream.on('tweets', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (tweet) {
  console.log(tweet);
  Tweets.insert(tweet);
})
});
```

Comment: jshint or jslint will be your friend.

Comment: You are declare variable inside a object literal, invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Twit = Meteor.npmRequire('twit');
var conf = JSON.parse(Assets.getText('twitter.json')); 

var T = new Twit
({
  consumer_key: conf.consumer.key, 
  consumer_secret: conf.consumer.secret,
  access_token: conf.access_token.key, 
  access_token_secret: conf.access_token.secret
});


  var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: conf.keyword })

  stream.on('tweets', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (tweet) {
  console.log(tweet);
  Tweets.insert(tweet);
});
```

Basically you closed your Twit constructor in wrong place, it's an object and you tried to put your code logic there

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript is structurally invalid.

You start creating an object here:

```
{
  consumer_key: conf.consumer.key, 
  consumer_secret: conf.consumer.secret,
  access_token: conf.access_token.key, 
  access_token_secret: conf.access_token.secret
```

But then suddenly you do this:

```
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: conf.keyword })
```

Hence the "unexpected token".  It's not really clear what you're *intending* for that code to do, but you can't create variables in the middle of declaring an object like that.